# How to re-enable content notifications for Notify?

Tags: notifications

I turned off content notifications for all users for [Notify](https://drupal.org/project/notify) some time ago because it was sending duplicates. There was a checkbox somewhere that I unchecked. It is not in notification settings.

This is Drupal 6.

Comment: Are you using any specific modules for notifications or just built-in core functionality?

Comment: it is the built-in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment on my question above, I guess you're using [Actions & Triggers in Drupal 6](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/trigger).

To see which actions you have defined or to define new actions, go to Administer > Site Building > Actions. There e.g. you can define an action for sending an email. From your question I think you already have done that (in the past).

To assign this action to an event, you have to go to Administer > Site Building > Triggers. There you can choose (under Content) to assign an action to an event, such as published or updated content.

Comment: no...I am not using anything other than the built-in functionality of the notifications module. When you turn it on, it sends plaintext emails to everyone every time a post is modified. I will have to look in to what you describe when I have time...but I never do; that's why I'm still on D6, etc.

Comment: So, then it's not Drupal Core functionality your're using, but a separate module? Is it this one: https://drupal.org/project/notifications

Comment: Sorry, I think I must have imagined the checkbox setting. I am using:Notify
6.x-1.2 Enables notifications of new content and comments by e-mail.
https://drupal.org/project/notify

Comment: No problem. Good thing you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no master checkbox or switch for the *admin* in [Notify](https://drupal.org/project/notify) (there is one for each user).

To turn of notifications for all users with one click, you disable the module, to turn it on again, you re-enable the module.  This is the same for the Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 versions.

As for the per user master switch, is can be found under *My account ➔ Notification settings*, as shown on the screenshot below.

[image]

For more about the use of this module, please see the [community documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/notify).

Answer (score -1):

The documentation I was looking for is here:
https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/notify

The "master switch" appears to be a feature of the D7 version of the module.

Comment: The statement about the "master switch" is wrong.  Please see my answer.